# PowerPoint 2016 - Stop Update Link Prompt

Tags: powerpoint

When opening PowerPoint I'm always prompted if I want to update the links to other files.

**-- How do I disable this prompt?**

I'm using PowerPoint 2016

*Here is a little info on what I'm trying to do:*

I have a few charts which link to an excel spreadsheet.

I've search high and low and all I can find it how to disable this for Excel, nothing related to PowerPoint?

I'm trying to get a PowerPoint presentation to open as a show and loop through the slides while updating the links automatically.

I've got the slides to update the data on each slide change but when opening directly to a show it's not working, I can only assume it's due to the security prompt?

I'm using this to update the slides:

```
Sub OnSlideShowPageChange(ByVal SSW As SlideShowWindow)
  ActivePresentation.UpdateLinks
End Sub
```

I hope someone can help.

Thanks in advance.

Dane